# devexpress column show/hide by click on checkboxes

Tags: devexpress, windows-forms-designer, devexpress-wpf

I want to add a column chooser with checkboxes at the header.

Is it possible to implemented this from run designer or any other way? I'm using windows forms to be more specific and DevExpress.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is not this functionality out-of-the-box. But, DevExpress provides the [E991: Creating quick column customization popup window](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Example/Details/E991) example that illustrates how to create a custom Grid to get it.